# Can't get my selection in WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn validated

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a WPF DataGrid where a column, actually a DataGridComboBoxColumn, is bound to a List, the binding works just fine. The problem is when I choose an element from the ComboBox's list it fills the field, but it becomes blank once I leave it, here is my code :

XAML :

```
<DataGrid Name="dgPrdCmd" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True"CanUserDeleteRows="True">
         <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
               <collections:ArrayList>
                     <local:TestData></local:TestData>    
               </collections:ArrayList>                                                        
         </DataGrid.ItemsSource>                                                                     
         <DataGrid.Columns>                                                        
             <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Product Name" x:Name="cb_NomPrdCmd" IsReadOnly="False"/>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity"/>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price"/>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and here's my C# :

```
using (_entieties)
{
     IQueryable<string> pName = from Product in _entieties.Products
                                select Product.prdName;
     foreach (var name in pName) 
     {
         prd.Add(id);          //prd is just a list of strings          
     }
}
//here is the most important part
cb_NomPrdCmd.ItemsSource = prd;
```

thanx in advance

Comment: what are the DataGrid columns bound to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not binding the `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem` of the ComboBox to anything, so no item will get selected.

Set either the `SelectedItemBinding` or `SelectedValueBinding` on your `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to maintain the selected item